# Input/output error using jmtpfs not saving file when copying to device

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I'm trying to mount an Android device on Debian using:

```
jmtpfs /media/mobile
```

But when I try to copy a file from my system to the device I get an input/output error saying that the file can't be closed.

Am I missing some parameter or something to enable the transfer?

Comment: Can you plese post the error output here, verbatim? Also, are you using root permissions to mount the device?

Comment: Please post the output of the above command with the `--verbose` switch included, `jmtpfs --verbose /media/mobile`.

Comment: Strange its working now, i tried the debug mode once with "jmtpfs -d /media/mobile" and after that the normal "jmtpfs /media/mobile/" both working, dunno what it was, sry guys

Comment: Strange, now trying again today i get can send files like .mp3 or .jpg but when i try to create a directory i get this in the debug:


unique: 222, opcode: LOOKUP (1), nodeid: 2, insize: 44, pid: 24405
LOOKUP /Cartão SD/ooo
getattr /Cartão SD/ooo
   unique: 222, error: -2 (No such file or directory), outsize: 16
unique: 223, opcode: MKDIR (9), nodeid: 2, insize: 52, pid: 24405
mkdir /Cartão SD/ooo 0755 umask=0022
   unique: 223, error: -5 (Input/output error), outsize: 16

Comment: it shows this prob only when i try to create a folder in the '/media/mobile/Cartao SD' which is the root of the SD card

Answer (score 2):

If your screen is locked, try unlocking the screen before attempting to connect. This did the trick for me.

source: https://wiki.debian.org/mtp

Answer (score 0):

If your file manager shows the device, it is already mounted. Try unmounting the device through file manager and running jmtpfs /media/mobile again.